# Looking for data science-oriented "Applied Maths for dummies" summer school

Tags: education, data-analysis, data-mining

I'm a PhD candidate who critically lake of maths skills for his data science projects. I'm looking for a summer school that would enable me to take off in this aspects.

This could be data-analysis/mining oriented, but still I really don't want to spend time to code or configure analysis frameworks. I would rather sit with pen and paper and unlock some maths understanding, formalism, thinking that can be useful for data science.

Does someone has cross something like this on a forum or mailing-list ? Or knows where I could ask, if not here ?

Nice image illustrating my question : https://lh3.ggpht.com/-vqpnsp0_22g/UGSwGDRcLwI/AAAAAAAAA7w/k-PQvvYuvbQ/s1600/Data_Science_VD.png

I don't want to keep staying in the "Danger Zone" :)

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you have a look at the courses on [coursera](https://www.coursera.org). In particular the [machine learning](https://www.coursera.org/course/ml) course, which is arguably the original and best course on coursera, is just about to run. This should give you a good intro to the maths that's relevant for data science in the context of the techniques that are used to do the analysis part of it. In my opinion the textbooks out there on machine learning tend to be of one of two extremes: either very hacky (which is what you want to move away from) or very mathsy (which is what you want to get to eventually but need a way in), so the coursera offerings are probably a good compromise to get you going.

There are plenty of courses on there related to math, but one you might not think of at first that I think might be very relevant to you is [Mathematical Methods for Quantitative Finance](https://www.coursera.org/course/mathematicalmethods). It covers a bunch of subjects that are mathematically very relevant including calculus, matrices and optimization (there is a question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/668574/77151) relating to the maths relevant for machine learning).